# Erlang connect by external ip address

Tags: erlang, ip

I write simple server application in erlang.

Code of this application: https://gist.github.com/783117

I try to connect to it with telnet. When I connect to localhost or local ip addres which get from route it's ok, but when i try to connect to server with external ip it's don't work.

What's wrong?

If i use options with {0,0,0,0}:

```
Opts = [binary, {ip, 0,0,0,0}, {reuseaddr, true},
            {keepalive, false}, {active, false}],
```

I get:

exception exit: badarg

> netstat -ltn | grep 110

tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:110        0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably, you opened the port bound a local address, but you'll have to check in which ip is your port listening to be sure. Could you run `netstat -ltn | grep 110` and `route -n`?

Comment: Firewall is another classic that might be a problem.

Comment: It should be `{ip,{0,0,0,0}}` not `{ip,0,0,0,0}` as in your code.

Comment: Thank you for correct variant. I added this. But external ip not connecting

Comment: Your netstat printout indicate that the gen_tcp is actually listening for traffic on all interfaces and the problem connecting might lay elsewhere. How about using a non-privileged port (>1024). Same behaviour?

Comment: I try 2000 port. problem still

Comment: Maybe that's really a firewall issue? Did you try turning it off to test the application?

Comment: I make port forwarding for 110 port in my route options. And i haven't firewall

Comment: Does port forwarding work for other services forwarded to the same host?

Comment: You should inspect the incoming traffic with e.g. Wireshark. Have you tried that?

Comment: This seems to be a networking problem, your netstat printout shows that erlang is opening the port correctly. This question has two parts: How I open a port listening on all interfaces in erlang? (already answered) and Why can't I connect to a port in my system from an external address (not answered and likely offtopic). I vote to leave the first one and, if you want, opening another for the second with enough data to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

From gen_tcp [manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#listen-2):

> listen(Port, Options) -> {ok, ListenSocket} | {error, Reason}
>
> ...
>
> Sets up a socket to listen on the port Port on the local host.
>
> ...
>
> {ip, ip_address()}
>
> If the host has several network interfaces, this option specifies which one to listen on.

I suppose your server listens only on the local host. That is, you can't connect using other addresses. You probably need to use the `ip` option. Maybe it's possible to use INADDR_ANY somehow like in C but I don't know.

[edit]

It appeared that it listens on INADDR_ANY by default even without `ip` option (thanks to I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS).
And I can connect from other machines with the original code shared by the author. However firewall is disabled on my machine

Comment: the way to listen in all interfaces is using `{0,0,0,0}` as ip

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {ip, 0,0,0,0}, you should pass: {ip, {0,0,0,0}}. You passed a tuple having 5 elements, instead of a tuple of 2 elements.